# Why are both of these values showing up as 100%?

Tags: r, pie-chart, dplyr

I'm trying to make a pie chart, and the first step is to calculate the actual percent share of each section. I thought I should be able to use `mutate` but it's giving me 100% across the board:

```
 starwars %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  count() %>%
  mutate(percent = n / sum(n) * 100)
```

I expected to see calculated percents, like this:

```
gender          n     percent
female          19      22
hermaphrodite   1       1
male            62      71
none            2       2
NA              3       3
```

[image]

But instead every row appears to be 100%:

```
gender          n     percent
female          19      100
hermaphrodite   1       100
male            62      100
none            2       100
NA              3       100
```

[image]

What do I need to change here so I'm getting the percent of the sum of n?

Comment: Try base R `with(starwars, prop.table(table(gender, useNA="ifany")))`.

Comment: I figured it out: what I want is 
`starwars %>%
  count(gender) %>%
  mutate(percent = n / sum(n) * 100) `

Comment: I'd love to understand the difference, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do ungroup first otherwise you are doing the `sum(n)` groupwise.

```
starwars %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  count() %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(percent = n / sum(n) * 100)
```

As noted in the comments, an alternate structure would be:

```
starwars %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  summarise(n=n(), percent = n / nrow(.) * 100)
```

Strictly, mutate adds the percentage to each row of the original tibble. summarise gives the summary requested.

Comment: Strictly, `mutate` adds the percentage to each row of the original tibble.  `summarise` gives the summary they request.  But you correctly identified the root cause of their proble, hence the upvote.  `starwars %>% group_by(gender) %>% summarise(n=n(), percent = n / nrow(.) * 100) ` removes the need for the `ungroup` and is a compact way of obtaining the requested result.

Comment: @Limey I used the code provided by OP and tried to amend it so that it yields the required result. Agree that your version of the code is more concise and succinct.